# Question about a files array and mime types

Tags: php

I need to make a script that will take files from a user and upload them to a server. I've already done this one and on my first attempt, I built in some checking to ensure that the correct mime type was being uploaded. Today, I have learned that browsers interpret mime types differently. This makes me think that maybe it isn't worth checking after all. The last thing I want is for a user to tell me that they can't upload a file because their browser doesn't handle mime types in the same way that my mine does.

What can anyone suggest. Should I forgo the mime type and check extension or is there a better way of doing this? I know that there is a CURL option for this but I think that is going to be overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php). Never rely on any data given to you by the user / browser for validation.

Comment: Thanks. Where are the docs? I only see User Contributed Notes there.

Comment: I agree with you about not trusting anything from the browser.

Comment: @Jim: Specifically, you'll want finfo_file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: Thanks Jason, I just found it myself. This is definitely the way to go. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an exclusion filter. Set your supported extensions (jpeg, jpg, gif, png, txt, doc, xls, etcetera), match them and test if the images files are indeed images with `getimagesize()`.

It's a different approach, I think it's slightly better since you don't want every filetype being uploaded.

Now that I think about it, you could implement both.

Good luck.